# how to use Click after Css selector in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using click for a statement it is not working. But without click it is going to that location:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='HeaderControlId']/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li/button")).Click();
IWebElement Element= driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.hasLeftControl:first-child"));
Element.Click();
```

Comment: What browser are you using ? 
Can you, please, describe your problem more than "it is not working" ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I am not getting any error but it is still not clicking. My problem is that it is going to the location but not clicking

Comment: @Didier I am using firefox.

Comment: @Mystia- Yes, if the click works it will go to another page where i can write texts

Comment: Is it the first thing you do on that page, wild guess maybe you need to wait till page load

Comment: No not the first thing.i have used wait command also.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, most likely you don't have the element that you are expecting or you need to click a different element. What I usually do in a situation like this is to do some debugging and make sure I have the element that I'm expecting. You can do things like

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.hasLeftControl:first-child")).Text;
```

and make sure the inner text is correct. You can also get `innerHTML`/`outerHTML` to verify the element.

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.hasLeftControl:first-child")).GetAttribute("outerHTML");
```

`innerHTML` gives you the element's descendants (the elements contained by the element specified). `outerHTML` does the same but includes the element specified.

[innerHTML JS reference with examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)